# How to merge multiple presentations (pptx slideshows) together with embedded objects in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, powerpoint

I have a problem with merging multiple PPTX slideshows into one with Apache POI when one XMLSlideShow contains an embedded Excel (XLSX) object.

The documentation looks like this
https://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html#Merge

```
XMLSlideShow pptx = new XMLSlideShow();
String[] inputs = {"presentations1.pptx", "presentation2.pptx"};
for(String arg : inputs){
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(arg);
    XMLSlideShow src = new XMLSlideShow(is);
    is.close();

    for(XSLFSlide srcSlide : src.getSlides()){
        pptx.createSlide().importContent(srcSlide);
    }
}

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("merged.pptx");
pptx.write(out);
out.close();
```

A PPTX file is created, but it is corrupted. The "PowerPoint couldn't read some content in merged.pptx".
I can see the that when loading the PPTX, the embedded excel is returned by the *getAllEmbedds()* method:

```
XMLSlideShow pptx = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("presentations1.pptx"))
PackagePart embedded = pptx.getAllEmbedds().get(0);
```

But it is not copied to the new XMLSlideShow when merging.
I am using POI 3.15

Still trying to do this in some other way.

Anyone managed to do that?